# What is the difference between do_execve() and execve() in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, execve

In the following [link](https://wenboshen.org/posts/2016-09-15-kernel-execve.html) I have the following code:

```
static int run_init_process(const char *init_filename)
{
    argv_init[0] = init_filename;
    return do_execve(getname_kernel(init_filename),
        (const char __user *const __user *)argv_init,
        (const char __user *const __user *)envp_init);
}
```

And it says the following:

> Here we can see that `kernel_init -> run_init_process -> do_execve`, which is the same with a regular execve syscall, the argument is init binary.

I'm trying to understand the difference between `do_execve()` and `execve()`. Why not to just use `execve()`?

Comment: It's just a function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Userspace communicates with kernel space using [syscalls](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). Both "spaces" - userspace and kernelspace - could be think of  separate programs that communicate with each other using registers and interrupts.

`execve()` is a [standard POSIX function](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) exposed by the operating system to C programs. It should be implemented by your standard library implementation, most probably you use [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/). On Linux most POSIX functions match the names of syscalls, so glibc just [implements a thin wrapper](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/glibc/+/cvs/glibc-2_1_93/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/execve.c#70) around the syscall.

When the syscall is called from a userspace programs, the parameters are saved on registers and an interrupt is triggered. That stops the execution of the userspace program and execution continues in kernel space.

Kernel grabs the parameters from userspace registers and executes a function that should handle the syscall. Most functions that handle syscall are just named `do_<syscall>` in kernel. The function `do_execve()` is just a function that kernel uses to handle `execve()` syscall from userspace.

> Why not to just use execve?

Why call the system call when you already are in kernel space? Just call the function that will handle the system call anyway.

Comment: Thank you! In theory, if I'll replace `execve` with `do_execve`, it will work? Or the Kernel does not allowed to use this function?

Comment: There is no `execve` function in kernel, to differentiate between kernel and user space.