# linux, systemcalls do_execv vs execv?

Tags: c, linux, unix, kernel, system-calls

Quoting from my lecture:

> Note the clear borderline between user space and kernel space. User
> programs cannot include kernel headers in their code and cannot call
> kernel functions directly. In other words, your program can’t simply
> call the sys_read() service function to read a file from the disk.
> Similarly, kernel code does not call user-space functions like
> printf(), does not include user-space header like <stdio.h> or
> , and does not link against user-space libraries like libc.
> The only gate to kernel mode (and OS services) that’s the user can use
> is the syscall instruction as described above.

1. "User programs cannot include kernel headers" So when I write in my C program `getpid()` is this user-space function?
2. What about when I type getpid in terminal is it the same (use-space function)?
3. I can't access linux header files in my system /home/user/linux-4.15 , so how it's said user space can't access kernel space?
4. Given the following image:

[image]

I have opened some linux file (init/main.c) and saw:

```
static int run_init_process(const char *init_filename)
{
      argv_init[0] = init_filename;
      return do_execve(getname_kernel(init_filename),....
}
```

where is this `do_execve` declared? the image shows only `execv` and `sys_execv`... and what's the difference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between do\_execve() and execve() in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62006709/what-is-the-difference-between-do-execve-and-execve-in-linux)

Comment: 1. getpid is a user-space function.  2. when you type getpid in the terminal it is the string "getpid".  3. Having a map of the Pentagon does not give you access to what's inside.  4. without knowing what file you opened, it is impossible to answer.

Comment: regarding 3 I can open those files what do you mean? in 2 I meant the function I am calling is it the user space function or the kernel space one?

Comment: For 4 it's init/main.c

Comment: @SergeyA ok then what's the difference between do_execv and sys_execv?

Comment: The kernel has both `sys_execv` and `do_execv`. `sys_execv` is the entry from the kernel's syscall dispatch table. It gets there when the userspace app calls (e.g.) the `glibc` function `execv`. It does this via the `syscall` inst. Once we're running in kernelspace, `sys_execv` calls `do_execv` to do the actual work. This separates the arg adjustments to handle userspace calls. But, doing an `exec*` operation is useful for the kernel to do on its own [in unrelated code]. That internal usage calls `do_execv` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "User programs cannot include kernel headers" So when I write in my C program getpid() is this user-space function?

Yes. It is a thin wrapper in `libc` that calls the system call. But depending on the architecture and the `libc` implementation, there might be some bookkeeping in userspace (e.g. caching the result for future calls).

For many simple syscalls, `glibc` generates these wrappers with preprocessor macros. On my system, a userspace call to `getpid` goes to file [`sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S):

```
0x00007ffff7ea6244  59  in ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S
(gdb) disassemble 
Dump of assembler code for function getpid:
   0x00007ffff7ea6240 <+0>: endbr64 
=> 0x00007ffff7ea6244 <+4>: mov    $0x27,%eax
   0x00007ffff7ea6249 <+9>: syscall 
   0x00007ffff7ea624b <+11>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

which simply puts the syscall number in a register and executes a `syscall` instruction.

The reason we are using this wrapper is to avoid having to know the specifics of the syscall mechanism and number for different architectures and kernels. This makes our program more portable. The `libc` we link against knows that `0x27` is `getpid` on this system, and that it should be written into `%eax` etc.

---

When the `syscall` instruction is executed, the processor switches into kernel mode and starts execution from [`arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S#L87), where `entry_SYSCALL_64` calls `do_syscall_64` which is in [`arch/x86/entry/common.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/entry/common.c#L39):

```
        regs->ax = sys_call_table[nr](regs);
```

You can see that it calls the function at index `nr` of the `sys_call_table`. This table is populated by a list of symbols (`sys_something`), where each one is defined by a macro: `SYSCALL_DEFINEn` where `n` is the number of parameters. Since `getpid` does not a parameter, it is defined as `SYSCALL_DEFINE0(getpid)` in [`kernel/sys.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/sys.c#L911):

```
/**
 * sys_getpid - return the thread group id of the current process
 *
 * Note, despite the name, this returns the tgid not the pid.  The tgid and
 * the pid are identical unless CLONE_THREAD was specified on clone() in
 * which case the tgid is the same in all threads of the same group.
 *
 * This is SMP safe as current->tgid does not change.
 */
SYSCALL_DEFINE0(getpid)
{
    return task_tgid_vnr(current);
}
```

---

> What about when I type getpid in terminal is it the same (use-space function)?

I don't know of a terminal command `getpid`, but if there is one, it would be an executable binary (or script) that eventually calls either a syscall, or a `libc` wrapper of a syscall. Because, the kernel maintains task and process IDs, and userspace code cannot access the kernel memory.

---

> I can't access linux header files in my system /home/user/linux-4.15 , so how it's said user space can't access kernel space?

Did you mean you CAN access the header files? You can access the entire source code, of course. But even if you include those headers in your program, and compile, and somehow link them with your kernel code, that doesn't mean you can run them in kernel mode.

Except, if you use *loadable kernel modules*. In fact, you need the kernel header files for compiling kernel modules. You can then **request** the kernel to load and execute those modules in kernel mode. But you need to call another syscall (`init_module`) to achieve that.

---

> where is this do_execve declared? the image shows only execv and sys_execv... and what's the difference?

Here is the definition of the syscall [`execve`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/exec.c#L2058):

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(execve,
        const char __user *, filename,
        const char __user *const __user *, argv,
        const char __user *const __user *, envp)
{
    return do_execve(getname(filename), argv, envp);
}
```

Similar to `getpid`, `execve` is defined with a `SYSCALL_DEFINEn` (this time three parameters) macro which generates the `sys_execve` symbol. Internally, the kernel calls `do_execve`. If you search the rest of the file, you'll see that `do_execve` itself is a wrapper around `do_execveat_common`. After some checks and initialization, `bprm_execve` is called, which calls `exec_binprm`, and so on.

---

> Can you elaborate what's the difference between `do_execve` and `sys_execve`?

Not much of a difference. Except, `sys_execve` symbol is defined by the `SYSCALL_DEFINE3` macro and is meant to be called by an architecture-specific syscall mechanism, which can be different from regular C functions (e.g. `asmlinkage`). `do_execve` is a regular C function. In this instance it isn't called from any other C code, but it is possible. Calling `sys_execve` directly from inside the kernel code however, would not be correct.

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate what's the difference between do_execve and sys_execve? still I don't get it

Comment: @john See the edit.